# How can I print a multidimensional array in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, matrix, printing

I am trying to print a multidimensional array (matrix) in Perl passing reference to array to subroutine.

Here is my code:

```
sub print_matrix(\@) {
      my $array = shift;
      for my $i ( 0 .. $#{ $array } ) {
        my $row = $array[$i];
        for my $j ( 0 .. $#($row) ) {
         print $array[$i][$j];
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use prototypes for Perl subroutines. Just `sub print_matrix { ... }` is correct

Comment: You should always use `use strict; use warnings;`. The compiler already caught your first error, and that would have caught the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print a two-dimensional Perl array very simply with something like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @arr_2d = (
    [ qw/ a b c d / ],
    [ qw/ e f g h / ],
    [ qw/ i j k l / ],
);

print_2d(\@arr_2d);

sub print_2d {
    my ($matrix) = @_;
    print "@$_\n" for @$matrix;
}
```

**output**

```
a b c d
e f g h
i j k l
```

---

**Update**

Here's a working version of your own code. You weren't using array references properly and had parentheses where there should have been braces. This version also prints a space after each element and a newline after each row.

```
sub print_matrix {
  my $array = shift;
  for my $i ( 0 .. $#{ $array } ) {
    my $row = $array->[$i];
    for my $j ( 0 .. $#{ $row } ) {
      print $array->[$i][$j], ' ';
    }
    print "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to access each element of an matrix

Comment: If my solution doesn't help you then you need to say a lot more about what you need. You asked how to print a multidimensional array and my code does that.

Answer (score 2):

Borodin tells you what was wrong with your code.

Now consider this module: **Data::Dumper** (available on CPAN). You can use this module to print any data structure: arrayref of arrayrefs (what you called a matrix), hashref of hashrefs, arrayref of hashrefs, hashref of hashrefs, or any other combination of these structures for as many dimensions as you want. Of course, if you have too many dimensions, it could lead to a confusing output.

My point is, some time ago, I was asked in an interview how I would implement this module. I thought it was a very clever question. I had to think a little because I use the module often but never bothered to figure how it works. It is in fact very simple. Imagine in your subroutine you receive a reference but you don't actually know what kind of reference it is (scalarref, arrayref, hashref, etc.), how would you determine what it is? If you have multiple possibilities, what would you do to cover all of them? Have you thought of creating a recursive function?

So, to solve your problem quickly, if you just want to print your matrix for debugging purpose, use **Data::Dumper**. Otherwise, if you want to do something more complex and wish to cover multiple cases, try to create a recursive function.

Here's a Data::Dumper example:

```
my $arrayref = [
    [ qw/ a b c d / ],
    [ qw/ e f g h / ],
    [ qw/ i j k l / ],
];

use Data::Dumper;

print Dumper $arrayref;
```

And here's the result you will get:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            'a',
            'b',
            'c',
            'd'
          ],
          [
            'e',
            'f',
            'g',
            'h'
          ],
          [
            'i',
            'j',
            'k',
            'l'
          ]
        ];
```

Each "row" of your matrix is printed as a list of elements, separated by a comma (and a new line), inside a pair of brackets. Be careful, if you pass it an array, it will print each elements one by one, and you will lose the "dimensions". If you only have an array, you have to pass it as a reference like this:

```
print Dumper \@array;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: `Data::Dumper` has been incorporated as a core module of every version of Perl 5, and so shouldn't need to be installed. But many prefer [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump) which produces much neater output. I appreciate your fascination with the cleverness of recursion, but I don't think it's useful as a solution to this question which is specifically about printing a 2D array.

Answer (score 2):

Using plain `print` is OK when all you have are single letter entries in your matrix, but a module like [Text::Table](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Table) can make it much easier to produce tidy output. For example,

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::Table;

my @matrix = map {
    [ map sprintf('%.2f', -500 + rand(1000)), 1 .. 5 ]
} 1 .. 5;

my $mat = Text::Table->new;
$mat->load(@matrix);

print $mat;
```

Output:

```
  -7.73  -83.85 -351.18   21.06  320.40
 174.83  238.29   91.16  361.43  213.04
 446.43   -4.82  322.81   10.38 -436.62
-128.05  195.68  199.05  288.39  115.30
-251.19 -329.35  244.13 -428.25  454.64
```